# Selecting data from DB where there are multiple records and fieldvalue is the same in both all records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table in SQL Server and I'm having a difficult time querying for the data that I need.

Here's what it looks like....

```
ClientNo          RecordNo           ApptDate
-----------------------------------------------
7                 1                  10/31/2016
7                 2                  10/31/2016
7                 3                  10/15/2016
9                 1                  11/12/2016
9                 2                  11/11/2016
18                1                  9/19/2016
```

So looking at this table - each client can have 1 or multiple records. I'm trying to find all clients that have more than 1 recordNo, and for all clients that have more than 1 record - I need to make sure to only display those that have the same ApptDate for both entries.

My end goal is to see this...

```
ClientNo         RecordNo        ApptDate
-------------------------------------------
7                 1              10/31/2016
7                 2              10/31/2016
```

So client 7 has 3 records (1,2,3) and the ApptDate is the for 2 out of 3 records. I only want to see the records where ApptDate is the same and skip the record where ApptDate = 10/15/2016 since it's irrelevant!

I have never done anything like this where I'm specifying that ApptDate = ApptDate and really haven't a clue how to do this.

Comment: can a `clientno` have more than 2 entries in the table? and if so, should you return all the rows for that client even if one set satisfies your conditions? or do you have to return that one set?

Comment: @vkp yes - there's no limit on how many they have. Typically it's 2 records for one specific date...so client has ApptDate, then calls in and cancels that ApptDate. I want to see only 2 records. Because in a typical scenario, Client will get a new ApptDate for rescheduled appointment. So seeing records for a single clients where dates aren't identical defeats the purpose. I basically want to see scheduled/canceled appts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
wHERE ClientNo IN (SELECT ClientNo
                   FROM mytable
                   GROUP BY ClientNo
                   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT RecordNo) > 1 AND
                          COUNT(DISTINCT ApptDate) = 1
```

The first predicate of the `HAVING` clause:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT RecordNo) > 1
```

filters out `ClientNo` values having only one related `RecordNo` value.

The second predicate of the `HAVING` clause:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT ApptDate) = 1
```

filters out `ClientNo` values being related to more than one `ApptDate` values.

**Edit:**

To get records having the same `ClientNo`, different `RecordNo` and the same `ApptDate` you can use a simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN mytable AS t2 
   ON t1.ClientNo = t2.ClientNo AND
      t1.ApptDate = t2.ApptDate AND
      t1.RecordNo <> t2.RecordNo
```

Comment: This will also show any other records for that client, which may not be on the same day. Admittedly, OP wasn't perfectly clear what he wanted, but my best understanding is that he only wanted to see the ones that were on the same day...

Comment: @JohnChrysostom I think this is what my query delivers. Please see the comments I made.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom - how am i unclear? I specified I needed to see Client records where there are more >1 RecordNo's and ApptDate is the same. I showed data sample and my desired end result

Comment: Suppose client 7 also has a record for 10/15/2016. Would you expect to see that record in your output? Giorgios' answer will display it.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom - I noticed that. It shows me everything. My apologies I hsould have included that in my Q.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom No, in that case client `7` would be filtered out due to the `COUNT(DISTINCT ApptDate) = 1` predicate. Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc334be/2) demo for a test case.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear... my understanding is that @Bobski would like to see the two records that share the same date in his output, but not the third that doesn't share that date...

Comment: @JohnChrysostom , you are correct. Show only data where recordno>1 and apptDate is the same. If client has 3 dates and 2 of them are the same and third isn't - i need to only see the 2 entries where ApptDate is the same

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos - beautiful. works like a charm. Thanks! Interesting way to do this - I was wondering How to get the ApptDate = ApptDate.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for... the window function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) will let you find clients that have the same date.

```
select
    clientno,
    recordno,
    apptdate
from
    (
        select
            clientno,
            recordno,
            apptdate,
            count(*) over(partition by clientno, apptdate) as numrecs
        from
            table
    )
where
    numrecs > 1
```